Angular 18 Polyfills warning
I just upgraded to Angular 18 and I get the following warning when I do ng serve:

▲ [WARNING] Polyfill for "@angular/localize/init" was added automatically. [plugin angular-polyfills]


In the future, this functionality will be removed. Please add this polyfill in the "polyfills" section of your "angular.json" instead.

angular.json
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser-esbuild",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/MyClientApp",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",

polyfills.ts contains the line:
...
import '@angular/localize/init';
...

What could be missing? I have in package.json the "@angular/localize": "^18.0.3",

The weird thing is. This was added by the migration scripts itself with the upgrade to Angular 8 at some point. At least in our code base. So looks like something is missing in the schematics for the upgrade to Angular 18.

Add "@angular/localize/init" to the polyfills array in your angular.json.
You can then delete your polyfills file if it only contains import '@angular/localize/init'; When I did this the warning went away.

This worked! I will keep polyfills.ts because i still have there import 'zone.js'; , but i will remove import '@angular/localize/init'; from polyfills and add it to angular.json.

You can also move zone.js into the array. For example, mine looks like this: "polyfills": ["zone.js", "@angular/localize/init"],

So but then are they removing the polyfills.ts completely or are they just unable to "see" you have localize in the polyfills file?
